# Apache disable previously set nokeepalive, downgrade-1.0, force-response-1.0

Tags: apache, variables, environment

We have a server running Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) for a bunch of legacy webservers. In the httpd.conf file is the following is set globally.

```
SetEnvIf X-Requested-With "^(?!XMLHttpRequest).*" !disable_keepalive
SetEnvIf disable_keepalive 1 nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

Is there a way within the httpd-vhosts.conf for a specific VirtualHost to disable/unset the environment variables for a specific server?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can SetEnv and UnsetEnv within the virtual host context.